# Using John or hashcat when password stub is leaked by weak crypto

Tags: hash, password-cracking, hashcat, john-the-ripper

I'm pentesting a system (call it X) which uses an internal secret key.  Due to weaknesses in the crypto, I can determine:

1. The SHA1 hash of the key (stored as a checksum)
2. With high probability, the value of any byte of the key
3. The len of the key
4. That the key consists only of printable ASCII chars

#2 is probabilistic, not perfect.  That is, if the key would be `secretkey!` I might predict `szcretyey!`.

I'd like to use my prediction as a base, and use [John EXTERNAL mode](https://www.openwall.com/john/doc/EXTERNAL.shtml) or [hashcat rules](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=rule_based_attack) to progressively modify it, replacing zero bytes, then one byte, then two bytes, each time with a printable ASCII char, until the SHA1 hash matches.

How can I do this?

*Note: I've already confirmed that the key does not appear in dictionaries or wordlists, and is too long to be cracked incrementally.

---

Update:

The rule would be something like:

```
N = 0
modify N chars
N++
```

Comment: You can leak the key bytes several thousand times and group them by frequency, So the first byte might be 80% s, 10% t, 1% a. Which should give you likely character combinations. Add to the fact that it appears to be a humanly generated key your brain should be able to filter these further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hashcat, there are two broad approaches (and the second is probably better for your use case):

First, you can do this with **rules**. For the first couple of levels, you can *start* to do this with multiple calls of a rule ("stacked" rule) file, each line of which simply overwrites (`o`) a single character in a single position with another character (`o0a`, `o0b`, `o0c`, and then `o1a`, `o1b`, `o1c`, etc.) The rules file should also contain the no-op "passthrough" directive `:` - so that stacking the rules file multiple times (`-r` file `-r` file etc) will get you one replacement, two replacements, etc.

But the challenge with this method is that the number of possibilities goes up quite quickly - `(94*wl)^x`, where `wl` is the word length in characters, and `x` is the number of changed characters. Even just replacing a single character in your example 10-character string is 940 possibilities. The first character or two aren't hard for a fast hash like SHA1, but you'll reach a feasibility limit pretty quickly:

```
940^1 = 940
940^2 = 883600
940^3 = 883600830584000
```

In practice, only a few million rules will fit within most GPUs' memory. So really, only the first two levels are likely feasible for most software and platforms.

Second, you can do this with **masks**. Since you have high probability, another approach would be  hold most of the string constant while varying the rest. You could do this with a file containing multiple masks, of the following form for a single character:

```
?aecretkey!
s?acretkey!
se?aretkey!
sec?aetkey!
secr?atkey!
secre?akey!
secret?aey!
secretk?ay!
secretke?a!
secretkey?a
```

... and this approach for two characters:

```
?a?acretkey!
?ae?aretkey!
?aec?aetkey!
?aecr?atkey!
?aecre?akey!
?aecret?aey!
?aecretk?ay!
?aecretke?a!
?aecretkey?a
```

... etc., rotating through all two-character replacements, then all three-character replacements, etc.

If the second (mask) approach is feasible for your use case, it is definitely more efficient - each mask is attacked separately, and has low memory requirements.